# How can I save cvMat in CoreData on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-data, opencv, transformable

I am using CoreData in my project. I can save UIImage by using UIImageToDataTransformer class in my project. Also I am using opencv library and I need to save some cvMat struct (they are structs, right?). I have read some posts about transformable but still cant figure out how to save it in coredata and fetch it back.

I have one entity called "Human" and it has a attribute called ProjVal and its type is transformable which holds data of cvMat.

What should my next step be?

Below its the transformer class for UIImage but how can I transform cvMat's data? Thank for your advices.

```
#import "UIImageToDataTransformer.h"
@implementation UIImageToDataTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(value);
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    return [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value] autorelease];
}
@end
```

**Edit:** Is it a better way to use its type as Binary Data type instead Transformable type? Im using auto-created classes for my entities.

I use this code while saving

```
CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    mat->data.fl[i] = 1.0f;
}


NSData *projValData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&mat length:sizeof(mat)];
human.projVal = projValData;
```

and while reading it back:

```
CvMat *mat;
NSData *data =  [[humansArray objectAtIndex:0] projVal];
memcpy(&mat,[data bytes],[data length]);
if (mat) {
    NSLog(@"if mat works");
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%f",mat->data.fl[i]);
    }
}
```

it doesnt work well and crashed in for loop. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get a pointer to (and size of) the raw bytes of your cvMat data?

If so, you can use the `dataWithBytes:length:` class method of NSData to in your `transformedValue:` implementation and the `bytes` (instance) method in `reverseTransformedValue:`.

Comment: I can get a pointer to cvMat and its size but still I cant use its type in my code. If you mean such functions   #import 

"ProjValTransformer.h" 

@implementation ProjValTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {  return YES;  }  
+ (Class)transformedValueClass {  return [NSData class];  }  
- (id)transformedValue:(cvMat*)value {  
return [NSData dataWithBytes:value length:sizeof(value)];  }  
- (cvMat *)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value { 
 return cvCreateMat(value.row, <#int cols#>, <#int type#>)  }  @end  


It gives error if I try to use cvMat like that.